# how to plot a box from three vectors with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have three vectors X, Y, Z originated from O(0, 0, 0):

```
1.02  4.30  1.50 0 ! X
5.33  5.05  5.60 0 ! Y
3.40  6.00  8.05 0 ! Z
```

I would like to plot (1) these vectors, (2) a box created from these three vectors, and (3) a point arbitrarily inside the box like the following picture. Can you show me how?

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced
set mapping cartesian
set output 'box_with_point.eps'
splot vectors.txt using 1:2:3:4:5:6 with vectors filled head lw 3
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is obvious: besides your 3 vectors you have to plot 9 additional lines.
However, this not too obvious *how* to do this with gnuplot.
Check the following example:

**Code:**

```
### plot unit cell
reset session
set view equal xyz
set view 80,72, 1.5
set xyplane relative 0
set border 4095

$Data <<EOD
1.02  4.30  1.50 0 ! X
5.33  5.05  5.60 0 ! Y
3.40  6.00  8.05 0 ! Z
EOD

$myPoint <<EOD
5.0  7.5   8.0
EOD

array X[3]
array Y[3]
array Z[3]
getXYZ(r) = (X[r+1]=$1, Y[r+1]=$2, Z[r+1]=$3)
myX(n) = X[(int($0)+n)%3+1]
myY(n) = Y[(int($0)+n)%3+1]
myZ(n) = Z[(int($0)+n)%3+1]

set key noautotitle

 splot $Data u (getXYZ(int($0)),0):(0):(0):1:2:3:0 w vec lc var lw 2, \
      $myPoint u 1:2:3 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "red", \
      for [i=1:2] $Data u 1:2:3:(myX(i)):(myY(i)):(myZ(i)) w vec lc "grey" lw 2 nohead, \
      $Data u ($1+myX(1)):($2+myY(1)):($3+myZ(1)):(myX(2)):(myY(2)):(myZ(2)) w vec lc "grey" lw 2 nohead
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition**:

Here is another approach which is maybe easier to follow and which simplifying the actual plot command. It's necessary to have the data in a datablock.

**Code:** (result same as above)

```
### plot unit cell
reset session
set view equal xyz
set view 80,72, 1.5
set xyplane relative 0
set border 4095

$Data <<EOD
1.02  4.30  1.50 0 ! X
5.33  5.05  5.60 0 ! Y
3.40  6.00  8.05 0 ! Z
EOD

$myPoint <<EOD
5.0  7.5   8.0
EOD

Value(row,col) = real(word($Data[row],col))
Xx = Value(1,1)
Xy = Value(1,2)
Xz = Value(1,3)
Yx = Value(2,1)
Yy = Value(2,2)
Yz = Value(2,3)
Zx = Value(3,1)
Zy = Value(3,2)
Zz = Value(3,3)

set print $UnitCell
    print sprintf("%g %g %g", 0    , 0    , 0)
    print sprintf("%g %g %g", Xx   , Xy   , Xz)
    print sprintf("%g %g %g", Xx+Yx, Xy+Yy, Xz+Yz)
    print sprintf("%g %g %g", Yx   , Yy   , Yz)
    print sprintf("%g %g %g", 0    , 0    , 0)
    print ""
    print sprintf("%g %g %g", Zx      , Zy      , Zz)
    print sprintf("%g %g %g", Xx+Zx   , Xy+Zy   , Xz+Zz)
    print sprintf("%g %g %g", Xx+Yx+Zx, Xy+Yy+Zy, Xz+Yz+Zz)
    print sprintf("%g %g %g", Yx+Zx   , Yy+Zy   , Yz+Zz)
    print sprintf("%g %g %g", Zx      , Zy      , Zz)
set print
 
set key noautotitle

splot $myPoint u 1:2:3 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "red", \
      $UnitCell w l lc "grey" lw 2, \
      $Data u (0):(0):(0):1:2:3:0 w vec lc var lw 2
### end of code
```

Comment: Many thanks, but is there any way to show vectors' names?

Comment: @BinhThien Check `help labels`.  In your case the 6th column contains the vectors' names. Add one line to the plot command  `$Data u 1:2:3:6 w labels offset 0,1`.